# How do I insert async to a log in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo

I want to use PyMongo as a logger for a Django app.

I don't mind if some inserts in the log table are lost, so I want to send a log to mongodb in another server, and continue the execution without waiting for confirmation.

I am reading pymongo docs, but it's not clear to me if the inserts in a collection are blocking or not.

I'm thinking of doing this inside a django model method

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
conn = MongoClient('mongoserver', 27017)
db   = conn.main
col  = db.log
col.insert({"user": "Pedro", "action": "search", "Origin": "Katmandu"}, w=0)
conn.close()
```

I don't know if I the insert is async like that and if the connection should be closed or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're passing a `w=0` parameter to `insert`, the operation is non-blocking and the call will simply queue the document for insert and return.

And leave the connection open for best performance.